# Why did npm stop bundling dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

npm client in the past used to place all items specified in `bundledDepenencies` in the `node_modules` in the package tarball. Since i've updated recently, it does not do it anymore and I have to specify the dependency in the `dependencies` rather than `devDependencies` which completely defeats the whole purpose of bundling dependencies since it adds a record to the yarn.lock file, triggering a download and an error from the fact that the package might be missing. My current version is 9.5.1, I'm not sure what the previous one was really but it did work just fine for years.

This is regardless of `bundleDependencies` spelling and/or using boolean value. You can check for yourself: pack a project using `npm pack` with a dependency listed in `dependencies`, then unarchive the tar and observe the node_modules folder inside which is good; then pack when the dep in in the `devDependencies`, repeat and node_modules won't be there. I thought the whole point of bundling dependencies is not to have a record in the `dependency` field! Yeah sure it might not be executed because it will be resolved to the inner one alright, but it will still be installed and like I'm using a private registry?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).